# PrimeNg Icons Not Showing (Checkbox and Select)

Tags: angular, primeng

[image: Checked box and select sans icons.]
*Checked box and select sans icons.*

I've added the primeicons library per:
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide

However, something is still a muck, I can't get the icons with show up.

**package.json:**

```
...
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
"primeng": "6.1.2",
```

also have, not sure if relevant. Doesn't seem like it's overwriting the css but possible

```
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
```

**html:**

```
<p-checkbox binary="true" label="Match Note"></p-checkbox>
```

**html showing icon class - from dev tools:**

```
<span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable pi pi-check" ng-reflect-klass="ui-chkbox-icon ui-clickable" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>
```

**css - from dev tools:**

```
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-icon {
    display: block;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-widget, .ui-widget * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
<style>…</style>
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-chkbox .ui-chkbox-box {
    width: 1.125em;
    height: 1.125em;
    line-height: 1.125em;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-active, .ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-active {
    border: 1px solid #156090;
    background: #186ba0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-state-active {
    border-color: #bebebe;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    color: #212121;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #555555;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-widget {
    /* font-family: "Roboto", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
    font-size: 1em;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-chkbox {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: .25em;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
<style>…</style>
.ui-widget {
    /* font-family: "Roboto", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
    font-size: 1em;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-card {
    background: white;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-card {
    /* font-family: Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif; */
}
Style Attribute {
    visibility: visible;
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-expansion-panel {
    background: white;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
<style>…</style>
.mat-expansion-panel {
    background: #fff;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.87);
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    /* font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"; */
    i": ;
    */: ;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
<style>…</style>
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    i": ;
    */i": ;
    */: ;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
<style>…</style>
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
<style>…</style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    i": ;
    */: ;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also include primeng.css, theme and primengicons under 'styles' section in angular.json.

```
"styles": [
     "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
     "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
     "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
]
```

Comment: Restart the app after adding this configurations to angular.json

Comment: Not to forget: npm install primeicons

Answer (score 19):

Try adding an import in style.css file

```
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

Comment: Amazing that they don't mention this in their documentation! ‍♂️

Comment: 100% works, This is Amazing.

Comment: This is insane ! It took me hours to figure this out. Even ChatGpt didn't gave me this answer! Thanks man <3

Comment: chatGPT will surely not solve all the problems, sometime software engineering is full of tricks. ha ha :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still not able to see the icons and styling after applying the suggestions in the accepted answer, try adding the css entries into your styles.scss file, that is what it took in my case.

```
@import  "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import  "~primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
@import  "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import  "~primeflex/primeflex.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be directly relevant, but I was trying to solve a similar problem with Search and placing a search icon within the text input.

The problem for me was z-index; the icon was there, but it was hidden behind the search input box!!

So setting the icon's z-index via CSS solved the issue (in my case, to 1).

```
.pi .pi-search {
z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `DropdownModule` and this one `CheckboxModule` and then this section to your `styles.css` file.

```
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented in primeng: In app.module.ts add "ButtonModule" under imports, could look like this:

```
...  imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
TableModule,
ButtonModule],
```

Comment: If you have a standalone component this is a must verify check

Answer (score 0):

change span font family in style.css to

```
span{
    font-family:'primeicons' !important
}
```

Comment: It should .pi not a span.

Comment: .pi { font-family:'primeicons' !important }

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still facing this issue, do check webpack loader config.

For me the issue was related to webpack loader:

After updating my code of webpack module loader from :

```
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
                use: ["url-loader", "file-loader"]
            }
```

to:

```
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|webp|svg|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
```

Icons started loading properly.