# PrimeIcons, icons lib are not showing after upgraded to angular 14

Tags: webpack, angular-material, icons, angular14, primeicons

Upgraded angular version from 8 to 14, external icons lib and fontstyle, primeicons not loading from nodemodules.

angular.json:
"styles": [                         "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",                         "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css",
"./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css" ],

package.json
"primeicons": "^4.0.0"`

style.scss:
`@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';`

Is this an issue deploy-url that is removed from ng serve command?

[image]

I tried
[PrimeNg Icons Not Showing (Checkbox and Select)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730724/primeng-icons-not-showing-checkbox-and-select)